# Встать прямо или стать прямо?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно говорить: "встать прямо" или "стать прямо"? Например, когда учительница говорит своему классу: "(В)станьте прямо"
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

"Встать" означает "подняться", а "стать" в данной ситуации - "зафиксировать положение стоя", поэтому "стать прямо" является верной фразой

Answer (score 1):

Согласно словарям, глаголы СТАТЬ/ВСТАТЬ являются многозначными и практически во всех случаях заменяют друг друга. В частности, можно отметит следующие значения: остановиться, принять вертикальное положение, расположиться, подняться, появиться/возникнуть и др. Хотя словари дают стилевые пометки для этих глаголов, разобраться в них довольно сложно. Например, нужно говорить: стань на ковер,  стул здесь не станет, стать у власти. Применить глагол ВСТАТЬ здесь также разрешается, но стиль будет разговорный.

Однако,  если понаблюдать за реальной речью, то практически во всех случаях применяется глагол ВСТАТЬ, а глагол СТАТЬ нам кажется уместным в роли связки, например:  он стал спортсменом, стало светло и т. д.

Встаньте прямо, разведите руки в стороны и т.д.  –  реально в этих случаях  практически всегда используется глагол «ВСТАТЬ».  Если в поисковике набрать «станьте  прямо», он выдаст, например, такое: «как СТАТЬ счастливее ПРЯМО сейчас».

Поэтому «СТАНЬ передо мной, как лист перед травой» и « СТАНЬТЕ дети, станьте в круг» звучит уже несколько архаично и часто меняется на ВСТАНЬ/ВСТАНЬТЕ. В то же время именно в этих примерах можно бы оставить «стать» в значении «появись» и «станьте в круг» в значении «станьте кругом».

Answer (score 0):

встать прямо будет правильней так как (стать прямо это звук) встать прямо

Answer (score 0):

Если подразумевается что человек находится в ином положении (лежит, сидит, криво стоит), то говорят "Встань (прямо), встань сюда". Когда я говорю, я часто глотаю букву В, и получается "стань", что может происходить и с другими, но пишется, по-моему, всё-таки с В.

На данный момент могу вспомнить только два исключения: *СТАНЬ передо мной, как лист перед травой* (Сивка-бурка), и *СТАНЬТЕ дети, станьте в круг* (песня про жука). Эти две фразы видела в обоих написаниях (и стать, и встать). Я не знаю, как правильно в этом случае, и могут ли оба варианта быть правильными.